# Forcing UIImagePickerController to shoot video in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, xamarin.ios

I've got a mostly-portrait iPhone application that needs to shoot some video, and I'd like to gently encourage (okay, force) users to shoot that video in landscape mode.

I've tried creating a `UIViewController` with `ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` overridden to return false, and appropriate `CGAffineTransforms` on its view, but it has no effect -- I assume because the view is out of the picture once you call `PresentModalViewController` to display the `UIImagePickerController`. The controls always show up in the same place, and the switch-to-front-camera control still moves around when I rotate the phone.

Any suggestions? I'd settle for definitive evidence that this isn't possible, though I'm not sure my boss would.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BeginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()` in your AppDelegate.

Then in the ViewDidLoad() method of your UIImagePickerController, add an observer by doing the following:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification", DeviceRotated);
}
```

where DeviceRotated is

```
private void DeviceRotated(NSNotification notification)
{
    button.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(1.5f);
}
```